# What happens on new Object which return new Object?

Tags: javascript

I have an object that I intend to return a new instance if target of operation is not already registered. A very simplified version of the code:

```
var Tangler = (function () {
    var targets  = [],  /* Array of targets Tangler operates on, no dupes. */
        registry = [];  /* Array of Tanglers operating on targets.         */

    /* Register new Tangler */
    function Tangler_entity(target) {
        this.id = registry.length;
        targets.push(target);
        registry.push(this);
        return this;
    }

    /* Public initiator.
     * Returns existing Tangler if one with target exists. */
    function Tangler(target) {
        var i;

        if (!target)
            return null;
        for (i = 0; i < targets.length; ++i) {
            if (targets[i] === target)
                return registry[i];        /* Return existing Tangler. */
        }
        return new Tangler_entity(target); /* Return new Tangler.      */
    }

    Tangler.prototype.some_function = function () {
        /* Operate on targets[this.id] */
    };

    return Tangler;

})();
```

Now, the intention is for this to be used as:

```
var tang = Tangler(some_target);
```

But, what happens when this code is run?:

```
var tang = new Tangler(some_target);
```

They both seem to operate OK, as in correct target get updated on either which, and no dupes are produced on `new new`.

Comment: when a constructor returns an object while using `new`, the returned object will be considered as the new object

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Yes, but on `new Tangler()` there becomes a double `new`. Also if one do `new` and an existing object is returned an update on one of them reflects on both.

Comment: yes.. both of them will be referring to the same object

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Wouldn't it then be a pointer to the first one? How can they be new objects if they refer to the same one? Doesn't that defy the meaning of an object? Or that by `var x = new Tangler(A)` a new object is created and as `new` is used it is cast to a pointer, and on second `var y = new Tangler(A)`, then `y` becomes a pointer to `x`. If one do a third `var z = new Tangler(A)` one end up with `z -> y -> z = Obj` and `y -> z -> Obj`. Where as if one does not use `new` one end up with `x = obj`, `y -> x` and `z -> x`.

Comment: I don't think so... because as the creator of the constructor you are explicitly returning an object so the js engine will respect your wish and treat the value returned by you was the new object. The js engine will not know whether the values was already returned by another call to the constructor